# jQuery plugin: .append() adds element to DOM but element is not visible?

Tags: jquery, frontend

I am trying to write my first jQuery plugin and have hit a snag quite early. The first part of my plugin needs to add a div into another div. It DOES do this, I can see in developer tools that the inner div is prepended, but it just isn't visible on the screen (even though developer tools says it has all the necessary styling and is appended).

Here is my plugin code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.skillBarLoad = function( ) {

    var prependedSkillBar = $("<div></div>");

    prependedSkillBar.css({
        "color": "#f9f9f9",
        "height": "100%",
        "width":  "100%"
    });

    return this.each( function() {
        $(this).prepend(prependedSkillBar);
    });

}

}(jQuery));
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your problem resides more in CSS than Javascript in my opinion... Relative heights will not always work as expected since it relies on parent nodes' styles. Check your parent's CSS and play with that. Also setting `background-color` instead of `color` will help you debug better.

Comment: Change your height in "px" and see whether its visible., I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful. Issue is fixed now! All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the color property which will only apply to text inside that div. Try setting the background colour instead like:

```
prependedSkillBar.css({
    "background-color": "#f9f9f9",
    "height": "100%",
    "width":  "100%"
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had morning brain and it was right in front of me the whole time. Thanks a lot as well  @Charleshaa. Both awesome.